# Ongoing computer lock up issue

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, memory, motherboard, sata

My system is as follows

Phenom II 945 stock
Gigabyte  GA-M720-US3
Windows 7 64bit
4GB Crucial DDR 2 4-4-12
Palit Geforce 460 GTX 
Samsung spinpoint F3 500gb HDD
3.5 inch floppy drive (yes...I know....)
Samsung DVDRW burner

Now the issue. Spontaneously and randomly my system will lock up. Literally. Mouse frozen, screen frozen. Cap/num/scroll lock not responding. Complete failure although the screen is still displaying. I can't seem reproduce this problem by stress testing. Tried prime95 and memory checkers. I can go for weeks at a time without having this problem. Sometimes its every day, or twice in one day!

One thing I can point out is when this happen and I hit reset, POST gets stuck at 'detecting IDE drives' forcing me to hard-power off the machine and turn it back on.

So am I thinking, is there a problem with the SATA cables, or HDD? Is connection to the HDD being interrupted? I checked the connectors and they all look fine.

The only other thing I can think of is a damaged motherboard.

Any thoughts on the problem here?

Comment: Run an HDD diagnostics, followed by a full system diagnostics (cpu, ram, etc.)